# Sort Linux file with dots and dash

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a veracode upload job that takes the jar files out of rpm packages and uploads to veracode. I am trying to sort it so that the latest version is last. But since the version number is after a dash it is messing up the sort I am trying to do. Here the the code and at bottom the current output. I have highlighted the current version.

```
GETRPM=`cat test.out|awk -F '\"' '{ print $2 }'|grep -v "^font*"|grep -v "^$"|sort -n| tail -1`

ap-apName-App-3.0.0-28.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-29.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-3.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-30.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-31.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-32.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-33.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-34.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-35.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-36.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-37.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-38.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-39.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-4.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-40.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-41.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-42.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-43.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-44.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-45.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-46.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-47.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-48.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-49.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-5.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-50.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-51.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-52.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-53.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-54.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-55.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-56.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-57.noarch.rpm
**ap-apName-App-3.0.0-58.noarch.rpm**
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-6.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-7.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-8.noarch.rpm
ap-apName-App-3.0.0-9.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
sort --version-sort test.out | tail -1
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you Phillippe! Worked like a charm.